# Is it possible to fake a Windows install for grub to add to boot menu?

Tags: windows, linux, grub, multi-boot

When doing a fresh install of a Linux distro (Ubuntu, for instance) on a fresh hard drive, if I want to install Linux first, and Windows later, is it possible to make grub *think* there's a Windows install on the first partition so that it'll be added to the boot menu after the installation is complete?

To illustrate, I have a new hard drive and have created two primary partitions (both still raw) and two logical (Ext4 and Swap). I want to install Ubuntu on the Ext4 partition first, and some version of Windows on the first primary partition only *after* that (because I currently don't have a Windows install disk, but do have one for Ubuntu). Is it possible to make Ubuntu add an entry for Windows right now and avoid having to repair grub after I've installed Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Do the Windows install first.**

That's generally how it should be done, for future reference. In your situation, I don't know much about Windows install behavior, but it **will always overwrite GRUB**.

You'll have to reinstall it no matter what you do.

---

The GRUB entry is like so:

```
title Windows
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

GRUB doesn't actually *check* for what you want to boot; it will assume you're correct. So, add it and don't use it.

Comment: you can backup the mbr using dd on the command line and restore it after windows is installed to skip having to go through a full grub re-installation.

Comment: @Evan True that, but `dd` has given me nightmares (I zeroed out my root partition). I think that for many users, the principle of "least privelige" definitely applies here.

Comment: lol, that's pretty funny. Maybe it's because I have brass ones in the face of breaking stuff but I don't even flinch when I use dd. Of course, I would consider multi-os installs to be a pretty advanced practice.

Comment: If you don't install GRUB in the MBR but on the partition itself, you could use the windows boot loader (edit boot.ini through system settings) to optionally boot from the other partition (linux). Or am I completely wrong? Windows will overwrite the MBR but not other boot loaders on other partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use grldr and boot using the native Windows boot loader:

http://grub4dos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Grub4dos_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

GRUB doesn't actually check for what you want to boot; it will assume you're correct. So, add it and don't use it.